# Common Lisp: Removing elements with the same cdr

Tags: list, lisp, common-lisp

(Assignment help, go easy on me) (I have to do this without using destructive functions (setf))

With common lisp, as part of some code I need to be able to:

Take a list of lists,
compare the cdr of 2 elements,
If equal disregard the first element,
If not equal then try and compare the first element with the next unchecked element in the list.

Some examples to clarify:

((1 1 1) (2 1 1) (3 1 1)) -> ((3 1 1))

((2 2 0) (4 1 1) (1 2 0) (3 0 1) (8 1 1)) -> ((1 2 0) (3 0 1) (8 1 1))

```
(defun simplify2 (vari)
    ;If last term: stop
    (if (equal (cdr vari) nil) vari

        ;If cdr of first and second term are equal...
        (if (equal (cdar vari) (cdr (cadr vari)))

            ;Ignore the first term and continue with the rest of the list
            (simplify2 (cdr vari))

            ;Otherwise (this is the line which isn't working)
            (cons (car vari) (simplify2 (cdr vari))))))
```

At the moment the code will only work properly when all 'like' terms are placed next to each other in the list.

Comment: `(remove-duplicates '((1 1 1) (2 1 1) (3 1 1)) :key #'cdr :test #'equal)`. Just saying.

Comment: sorry, updated to say i cant use destructive functions

Comment: [remove-duplicates](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_rm_dup.htm) is not destructive, `delete-duplicates` is. But I guess you'll have to implement it yourself.

Comment: Your algorithm cannot work since two sublists with equal cdrs are not necessarily successive in your list.

Comment: What does "If equal create disregard the first element," mean?

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor for example ((1 1 0)(2 1 0)) -> ((2 1 0)) since the cdr of the 2 elements are equal

Comment: @HarryHartley I understand what the examples show;  I'm not sure what you mean by "create disregard the first element".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Le Petit Prince's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27386201/common-lisp-removing-elements-with-the-same-cdr/27386909#comment43220842_27386201) in the comments to use **remove-duplicates** is probably what you want here.  **remove-duplicates** is non-destructive (cf. **delete-duplicates** which can be destructive), and it's specified to a return a new list in which all but the last instance of an element are omitted (emphasis added):

> #### [remove-duplicates](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_rm_dup.htm)
>
> **remove-duplicates** returns a modified copy of sequence from which any
>   element that matches another element occurring in sequence has been
>   removed. … The elements of sequence are compared pairwise, and
>   if any two match, then *the one occurring earlier in sequence is
>   discarded*, unless from-end is true, in which case the one later in
>   sequence is discarded.

You'll need to specify the a **key** argument to indicate that what should actually be compared is the **cdr** of the elements, and a **test** argument to indicate that they should be compared with **equal**.  Thus:

```
(remove-duplicates '((1 1 1) (2 1 1) (3 1 1))
                   :test 'equal 
                   :key 'cdr)
;=> ((3 1 1))
```

```
(remove-duplicates '((2 2 0) (4 1 1) (1 2 0) (3 0 1) (8 1 1))
                   :test 'equal
                   :key 'cdr)
;=> ((1 2 0) (3 0 1) (8 1 1))
```